# С++. Полный путь к исполняемому файлу (с именем)

Tags: c++

Всем привет.
Возможно я кривой, слепой или т.п, но я не нашел. На шарпе я это делал с помощью  класса Assembly.
Мне нужно что бы при запуске выводилось окно с полным путем исполняемого файла. К примеру я запустил его по этой директории: `"C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\MyFile.exe"`
И при запуске он мне пишет:

```
C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\MyFile.exe
```

То есть даже если я изменю имя, папку, то он должен выдавать точно так же. К примеру я изменил имя файла на MyFileFileFile.exe и при запуске он выдаёт:

```
C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\MyFileFileFile.exe
```

Если изменю папку к примеру на `Source` то он должен выдать:

```
C:\Users\Asus\Source\MyFileFileFile.exe
```

Надеюсь поняли.

Comment: 0 параметр вызова main?

Comment: @pavel хм, да. Я однозначно тупой :D

Comment: `GetModuleFileNameW` c дескриптором этого модуля

Comment: Если ваш вопрос привязан к конкретной ОС, то на вопросе должна стоять метка этой конкретной ОС.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

/proc/self/exe - вернет линк на текущий pid (Linux)

Windows: GetModuleFileName

Linux:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <unistd.h>


int main()
{
    std::string path;
    path.resize(1024);

    auto ret = readlink("/proc/self/exe", &path[0], path.size()); // &path[0] - не const char*

    path.resize(ret);

    if (path.at(0) == 0)
    {
        std::cout << "Error" << std::endl;
        return -2;
    }

    std::cout << path << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Windows:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    WCHAR path[500];
    DWORD size = GetModuleFileNameW(NULL, path, 500);

    std::cout << path << std::cout;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: То, что у вас получилось, еще не является корректным. Вы выводите `path`, размер которого равен `1024` и где-то внутри которого сидит `\0`, и надеетесь, что `std::cout << path` остановится на `\0`. Это не гарантируется. Вам нужно еще после `readlink` сделать еще что-то вроде `path.resize(ret)`.

Comment: Уже сделал же))

Comment: Ненужный `#include <vector>` остался... А где нужный `#include <string>`? :O) (Я не минусую. Не знаю, кто это ополчился)

Comment: Забыл поменять)

Comment: Да есть один обиженный

Answer (score 1):

Это параметры функции main (argc, argv) то что вам нужно и есть argv

Comment: Нет никакой гарантии, что в `argv[0]` будет полный путь.

Comment: Возможно, хотя и не попадалось, а вот GetModuleFileName мне врал безбожно в немецкой локали winXP

Comment: @pepelxl Вам стоило задать соотв. вопрос.