# Как использовать png в winapi

Tags: c++, winapi

Есть ли какие-то способы использовать png/jpg изображения без добавление их в папки пользователя? Например, у пользователя находится проект в папке **Папка/Проект/.exe**. Чтобы вывести картинку надо к ней обратиться **Папка/Проект/.png**. Как можно обратиться к картинке, не загружая ее к пользователю? Используется c++(17 - gcc)

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1045770/%d0%a1-%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d1%8f%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%bc%d1%83-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d1%83-%d1%81-%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bc

Comment: @Chorkov Я имел ввиду, чтобы не обратиться к папке, а наоборот загружать через gdi+ (например), не имея самих файлов у пользователя

Comment: @Julji Ищите как положить файлы в ресурсы исполняемого файла?

Comment: @Chorkov Что-то вроде этого, но у меня компилятор не от vs

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54224417/g-include-rc-files-from-cmd